# BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics throwing Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFF7 in BluetoothApis.dll

Tags: c#, c++, .net, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to write a Win32 console application that will connect iPhone Bluetooth for some BLE services. Please correct me if I am making any mistake here-

Getting Access violation error at -

```
hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(
    hLEDevice,
    pServiceBuffer,
    0,
    NULL,
    &charBufferSize,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);
```

The reason is, I am not able to loop through - `SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces` for this device classId.

Main function for more detail-

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <setupapi.h>
#include <devguid.h>
#include <regstr.h>
#include <bthdef.h>
#include <Bluetoothleapis.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "SetupAPI")
#pragma comment(lib, "BluetoothApis.lib")

HANDLE GetBLEHandle(__in GUID AGuid)
{
    HDEVINFO hDI;
    SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA did;
    SP_DEVINFO_DATA dd;
    GUID BluetoothInterfaceGUID = AGuid;
    HANDLE hComm = NULL;

    hDI = SetupDiGetClassDevs(&BluetoothInterfaceGUID, NULL, NULL, DIGCF_DEVICEINTERFACE | DIGCF_PRESENT);

    if (hDI == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return NULL;

    did.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA);
    dd.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVINFO_DATA);

    for (DWORD i = 0; SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces(hDI, NULL, &BluetoothInterfaceGUID, i, &did); i++)
    {
        SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA DeviceInterfaceDetailData;

        DeviceInterfaceDetailData.cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

        DWORD size = 0;

        if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDI, &did, NULL, 0, &size, 0))
        {
            int err = GetLastError();

            if (err == ERROR_NO_MORE_ITEMS) break;

            PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA pInterfaceDetailData = (PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, size);

            pInterfaceDetailData->cbSize = sizeof(SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA);

            if (!SetupDiGetDeviceInterfaceDetail(hDI, &did, pInterfaceDetailData, size, &size, &dd))
                break;

            hComm = CreateFile(
                pInterfaceDetailData->DevicePath,
                GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                0,
                NULL);

            GlobalFree(pInterfaceDetailData);
        }
    }

    SetupDiDestroyDeviceInfoList(hDI);
    return hComm;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){

GUID AGuid = GUID_DEVCLASS_BLUETOOTH;



//now get the handle 
HANDLE hLEDevice = GetBLEHandle(AGuid);


//Step 2: Get a list of services that the device advertises
// first send 0,NULL as the parameters to BluetoothGATTServices inorder to get the number of
// services in serviceBufferCount
USHORT serviceBufferCount;
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Determine Services Buffer Size
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

HRESULT hr = BluetoothGATTGetServices(
    hLEDevice,
    0,
    NULL,
    &serviceBufferCount,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

if (HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA) != hr) {
    printf("BluetoothGATTGetServices - Buffer Size %d", hr);
}

PBTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE pServiceBuffer = (PBTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE)
    malloc(sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE) * serviceBufferCount);

if (NULL == pServiceBuffer) {
    printf("pServiceBuffer out of memory\r\n");
}
else {
    RtlZeroMemory(pServiceBuffer,
        sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_SERVICE) * serviceBufferCount);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Retrieve Services
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

USHORT numServices;
hr = BluetoothGATTGetServices(
    hLEDevice,
    serviceBufferCount,
    pServiceBuffer,
    &numServices,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

if (S_OK != hr) {
    printf("BluetoothGATTGetServices - Buffer Size %d", hr);
}


//Step 3: now get the list of charactersitics. note how the pServiceBuffer is required from step 2
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Determine Characteristic Buffer Size
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

USHORT charBufferSize;
hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(
    hLEDevice,
    pServiceBuffer,
    0,
    NULL,
    &charBufferSize,
    BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

if (HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_MORE_DATA) != hr) {
    printf("BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics - Buffer Size %d", hr);
}

PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC pCharBuffer;
if (charBufferSize > 0) {
    pCharBuffer = (PBTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC)
        malloc(charBufferSize * sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC));

    if (NULL == pCharBuffer) {
        printf("pCharBuffer out of memory\r\n");
    }
    else {
        RtlZeroMemory(pCharBuffer,
            charBufferSize * sizeof(BTH_LE_GATT_CHARACTERISTIC));
    }


    USHORT numChars;
    hr = BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics(
        hLEDevice,
        pServiceBuffer,
        charBufferSize,
        pCharBuffer,
        &numChars,
        BLUETOOTH_GATT_FLAG_NONE);

    if (S_OK != hr) {
        printf("BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics - Actual Data %d", hr);
    }

    if (numChars != charBufferSize) {
        printf("buffer size and buffer size actual size mismatch\r\n");
    }
}
```

Getting error

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F5CE138 (BluetoothApis.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location
>   0xFFFFFFF7

Can anyone suggest what could be the cause?

I tried with a C# desktop application but no luck there also getting the FileNotFound error at the line "`await GattDeviceService.FromIdAsync(device.Id)`"

Comment: Would that not be because the device is not currently connected?

Comment: Did you confirm that all of the parameters you are passing to the BluetoothGATTGetCharacteristics function are correct and valid??

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I have added more details for this question. Do you think it is enough or needs more info? Do you mind to check this out now?

Answer (score 0):

The question is old, but there still no answer. This is due to `GetBLEHandle` function that returned NULL. `AGuid` is a GUID of BLE device (in Microsoft samples it's HRM - heart rate monitor), you have no device with this GUID connected. So `NULL` from `GetBLEHandle` is `DEVICE_NOT_FOUND`. And if you'll call `BluetoothGATTGetServices` with `NULL` deviceHandle you'll receive such exception.